# jquery hover overlay with caption

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, overlay, caption

I want to achieve a hover overlay effect with caption on my portfolio.
I'm am listing my work using a basic nav ul li a img, and I simply want a black overlay with some white text, when hovering over a specific reference(image with link)

So far i've got this, but it apparently it disrupts my link, so it is just a simple hover overlay, and I can't seem to get the caption integrated correctly. Also the fadeIn transition is pretty much non existing at the moment.

```
THE HTML

<section id="portfoliowrapper">
<nav>
 <ul class="colum3">
        <li><a href="portfolio_detail.aspx" title=""><img src="/images/webraket_single_item.jpg" alt="webraket_single_item"  /></a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio_detail.aspx" title=""><img src="/images/businesscards_single_item.jpg" alt="businesscards_single_item"  /></a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio_detail.aspx" title=""><img src="/images/webraket_single_item.jpg" alt="webraket_single_item"  /></a></li>

 </ul>
</nav><!-- //navcontainer -->
</section><!-- //portfoliowrapper-->

MY CSS

 #portfoliowrapper { float: left;}
 #portfoliowrapper nav .colum3 { float: left;}
 #portfoliowrapper nav .colum3 a img { }
 #portfoliowrapper nav .colum3 li {float: left;width: 253px;height: 220px;margin-right:    10px;margin-bottom: 10px; background: #555; }
 #portfoliowrapper nav .colum3 li:last-child { margin-right: 0px;}

THE J

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.colum3 li a').bind('mouseover', function () {

        $(this).parent('li').css({ position: 'relative' });
        var img = $(this).children('img');
        $('<div />').text(' ').css({
            'height': img.height(),
            'width': img.width(),
            'background-color': '#000',
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': 0,
            'left': 0,
            'opacity': 0.6
        }).bind('mouseout', function () {
            $(this).fadeOut('fast', function () {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }).insertAfter(this).animate({
            'opacity': 0.6
        }, 'fast');

    });

});
</script>
```

When I hover over a reference, the black overlay comes along with caption, and I can click on the picture to go to the specific reference.

Comment: Something like this? [http://thisdeveloperslife.com/](http://thisdeveloperslife.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start - I ditched the overlay div in favor of an overlay text bit, and fade the image itself. As long as the background is dark/black, it looks the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/g6xVR/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you use a  instead of a , you can insert the tag inside the  tag, which won't  disrupt your link. Just set the span css to "display: block"

If possible, I would recommend writing the captions out in your markup and then hiding them via CSS until the mouseover occurs. It's faster than creating and removing a DOM element on each mouseover.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jesus_tesh/fGXXX/)

This uses the title attribute to display in the overlay. The image paths are not full paths, so the fiddle doesn't display your images (so it is not perfect), but you get the idea.

Comment: Hey. This is almost what I seek. But still, my links is disruptet by the code. At the moment it is still just hover without links. And still, I cant seem to find the way to correct it.

Comment: Another thing... Is there a way to control the position of the title? Thanks again

Comment: Check it out now. I set the height of the message to half image height.I also wrapped the div in an <a> that links to the same place as the image. That allows the hover text to be clickable.